# Ruby: how to call subclass views from superclass method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, methods

So I get the convention over configuration and how a class' methods are tied to their views, great. But, for example, what if I want to handle methods that are identical for all subclasses with a method in the superclass, and then render the appropriate view in the superclass method.

For example, I have a several classes that are subclasses of the Section class. Each of these subclasses has an edit method and view:

```
class CalendarsController < ApplicationController
...
  def edit
    @calendar = Calendar.find(params[:id])
    render layout: false
  end
end
```

and the superclass method includes its own edit method, which redirects to the subclass method:

```
  class SectionsController < ApplicationController
     ...
     def edit
       @section = Section.find(params[:id])
       case @section._type
         when "Calendar"
           redirect_to edit_organization_bulletin_calendar_path(@organization, @bulletin, @section)
        end
     end
     ...
   end
```

Is there a way I can eliminate all of the subclass edit methods and just directly access the correct model view from the superclass' method? Seems this would be more elegant, more... ruby-like.

Comment: Do you need the superclass method?  If it doesn't exist, the matching method in the subclass should get called.

Comment: I have the method on the superclass with the redirect and on all of the subclasses as well. But the whole point is to keep it DRY... when I need to do other common operations on the subclasses I only have one method to maintain, the one on the superclass.I could do the same IF there were a way to call the subclass views from within the superclass (and of course I'd rather not hard-code the link into the superclass method, that would kind of defeat the purpose).

Comment: I guess I'm not able to picture your inheritance structure.  Perhaps you could edit your question to include more of your code?

Comment: the children should inherit from your parent, not ApplicationController: `class SectionsController < ApplicationController` and then the children: `class CalendarsController < SectionsController`. After this, in the parent's edit action you could use a `params[:type]` and `params[:id]` to find back the record you want to edit.

Comment: Ok, the models all inherit from Section, should the controllers also? But that's a different question. 

My question is this: what code do I write to replace the redirect_to in the super class method, that will render the appropriate subclass edit view without actually calling the subclass' view method? Something like:

render edit_organization_bulletin_calendar_path...